# Ridge Regression Implementation

Tags: regression, ridge-regression

I'm working through the math of ridge regression and am having some trouble replicating some R functions. My question is NOT about R, per se, I will just use it here for a reproducible example but really am trying to learn how to build an implementation. I'm assuming the R code implementations are correct and that mine is incorrect for now.

Let $\bf{X}$ be an $n \times p$ model matrix, $\bf{y}$ be an $n \times 1$ vector of outcomes, $\lambda$ is some scalar, and $\bf{I}$ is a $p$-dimensional identity matrix. The algebraic representation of the estimator is written

$$
\bf{\hat{\beta}} = (\bf{X}'\bf{X} + \lambda\bf{I})^{-1}\bf{X}'\bf{y}
$$

I use the term "algebraic" representation to mean a way to write the estimator, but the computational implementation might use a decomposition (e.g., QR/Cholesky) or augment the rows of $\bf{X}$ and $\bf{y}$. With that said, for purposes of my question, my code will look like the algebraic representation for some transparency.

This link here provides an example to use for learning ridge regression in the glmnet package and my code below is based on the objects created in this example, https://github.com/Statology/R-Guides/blob/main/ridge_regression.R

```
### Add intercept
X <- cbind(1,x)
theDiagonal <- diag(c(0, rep(best_lambda, 4)))
solve(crossprod(X) + theDiagonal) %*% crossprod(X,y)
### Do as an OLS 
lm(y~0+X)
solve(crossprod(X)) %*% crossprod(X,y)
```

The results of my home baked ridge estimation do not match those coming from the glmnet functions, but my home baked OLS does match internal OLS functions.

My question does seem to partly duplicate this question, but the answer here is not entirely transparent to me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163589/customized-ridge-regression-function

I've made a few assumptions here. First, no penalty is added to the intercept and also no rescaling of the predictors is used. If it is needed, I'm unclear on why. Nonetheless, I have also tried scaling the predictors be marginally be $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ and I do not match even when doing so that way.

Clearly I have a misunderstanding and would appreciate any guidance to help me in my learning.

#### EDIT: Adding in code and results from glmnet per suggestion

```
library(glmnet)

#define predictor and response variables
y <- mtcars$hp
x <- data.matrix(mtcars[, c('mpg', 'wt', 'drat', 'qsec')])

#fit ridge regression model
model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)
summary(model)

#perform k-fold cross-validation to find optimal lambda value
cv_model <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0)
plot(cv_model)

#find optimal lambda value that minimizes test MSE
best_lambda <- cv_model$lambda.min
best_lambda

#produce Ridge trace plot
plot(model, xvar = "lambda")

#find coefficients of best model
best_model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, lambda = best_lambda)
coef(best_model)

5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    s0
(Intercept) 479.381278
mpg          -3.261227
wt           21.440464
drat          1.169642
qsec        -19.069106
```

Results from my code yields

```
> solve(crossprod(X) + theDiagonal) %*% crossprod(X,y)
            [,1]
     523.7308078
mpg   -4.7963814
wt    12.8262329
drat   0.9825495
qsec -18.2354511
```

Comment: why `theDiagonal` is defined that way? First of all, why "0" and "4" in the definition? Secondly, are you sure it is an order $p$ matrix instead of a vector?

Comment: Hi @Zhanxiong. My code should have made theDiagonal a matrix and not a vector. That was an error. Code in the question is edited now.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a true reproducible example indicating the discrepancy between the results you are targeting and your actual results. This could be a misunderstanding about what the `glmnet()` code does and not an error in your representation of RR.

Comment: If $p = 4$, then shouldn't `theDiagonal` be defined as `theDiagonal <- diag(rep(best_lambda, 4))`?  $X$, of course, needs to be centered first.

Comment: @Zhanxiong that's part of my question. In my assumptions above I state I do not added the penalty to the intercept and I could be wrong. If we do as you suggest, it would add the value of best_lambda to all diagonal elements including the intercept.

Comment: What is the question? Can you bring this more clearly in this relatively long story.

Comment: @Noah, code updated per suggestion

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus the question is why my home baked implementation of the RR does not match glmnet's implementation. My assumption is the codes above should be comparable--an assumption I am not certain of.

Comment: @dhc Thank you for that. Your code and question are clear to me but unfortunately I do not know the answer to this question. It's possible `glmnet()` scales its lambda in a particular way. For example, if I divide `best_lambda` by 2.103735, I get approximately the same coefficients when using this value in the manual calculation. Not sure why.

Comment: I know the answer to these issues: First: 'glmnet()` standardizes the variables by default so yeah... `standardize = FALSE`, second: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126109/coefficient-value-from-glmnet i.e. the betas are further scaled by the size of the dataset. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155362 for further discussion too. In short, welcome to the `glmnet` hole, where all roads lead to reading FORTRAN code. Your code and understanding are correct so (+1).

Comment: (And do not we are using coordinate descent right? That's not *the* world's solver so yeah, some minor movements away from the optimum are also in store.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replicating results for glmnet linear regression using a generic optimizer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236866/replicating-results-for-glmnet-linear-regression-using-a-generic-optimizer) (I mean it should. :) )

Comment: (and not forget that as the `cv.glment` needs some seed fixing first otherwise we get different `best_lambda` given how small our dataset is.)